# android studio compile errors not ordered and not clickable

Tags: android-studio, android-jack-and-jill

I am using jack with android studio

When I have compilation errors the errors are mixed in with the warnings and are thus annoying to locate and once located you cannot click on them to go to the relevant section in code

See example below:

[image]

I would like to show the errors only (or have them grouped together) and then have them clickable to go the line of the source file.